# How can i count lines in file

Tags: linux, debian, cat

I need to count how many times different IP's were in the file.

I'm using this to open file because i don't have `grep` rights to do it only with `grep`

My Rights

```
User lotarc may run the following commands on herbert:
    (root) /bin/su - censored
    (root) /bin/su - censored
    (root) /bin/cat /var/log/nginx/access.log, /bin/cat /var/log/nginx/access.log.1, /bin/zcat /var/log/nginx/access.log.[0-9]*.gz, /bin/cat /var/log/nginx/error.log, /bin/cat /var/log/nginx/error.log.1, /bin/zcat
        /var/log/nginx/error.log.[0-9]*.gz
```

```
sudo cat /var/log/nginx/access.log.1 | grep -E '1ip|2ip|3ip'
```

My question is how to count this ip's and get the output. I need to count from multiple files like access.log.2.gz

Content of file

`some ip - - [30/Sep/2019:07:26:03 +0300] "POST /clientapp/request/signUp HTTP/1.1" 200 0 "-" "python-requests/2.22.0" "-"`

Comment: @msp9011 Of course.
I need to count specific ip`s
Check my edit to see content

Comment: And i guess i need to count each ip's, how many times it does this request from the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
cat access_log | awk '{a[$1]++} END {for(i in a) print a[i],i}' | sort -n | tail -n1
```

For specific IPs:

```
cat access_log | awk '$1 == "192.168.1.37" || $1 == "192.168.1.110" {a[$1]++} END {for(i in a) print a[i],i}'
```

Comment: It's working well. Now i'm going to try to sort it, because there's many ip's i want to find only with the highest value of requests

Comment: If you are trying to find the highest value, I think a combination of sort and uniq can help you, if you can use those.

Comment: @msp9011  I found a problem. Your first code is adding 0 after ip like
`34228 91.219.253.1100`
but it's should be
`34228 91.219.253.110`

Comment: @number9 I tried to use sort and uniq, but it doesn't help me.

Comment: @SemyonKolesnikov it shouldn't be... can u share few lines with those IP?

Comment: It's for every ip
`18 46.211.37.1730
2 66.249.79.110
32 128.124.243.940
`

Comment: @msp9011  cat access.log | awk '{a[$1]++} END {for(i in a) print a[i],i}' |sort -nr

Comment: @number9 Thank you very much. It worked well, and i got much needed results. Thank you

Comment: @SemyonKolesnikov couldn't help without knowing the content....

Comment: @msp9011 But I added content in my question, and answered all questions)

Answer (score 1):

I might be off my rocker, but this looks straightforward if you just want the count.

```
 awk '{print $1}' access.log |uniq |wc -l
```

This will output the count from the one file. If you want all of them you could zgrep all of them and use the dreaded IP address regex:

```
zgrep '\(25[0-5]\|2[0-4][0-9]\|[01][0-9][0-9]\|[0-9][0-9]\)\.\(25[0-5]\|2[0-4][0-9]\|[01][0-9][0-9]\|[0-9][0-9]\)\.\(25[0-5]\|2[0-4][0-9]\|[01][0-9][0-9]\|[0-9][0-9]\)\.\(25[0-5]\|2[0-4][0-9]\|[01][0-9][0-9]\|[0-9][0-9]\)' access.log.*.gz | awk '{print $1}' | uniq |wc -l
```

Of course, I bet there is a much simpler way that some clever person can give you, but it is a bit early in the morning for me, I am just throwing this solution out there. Tested on my webserver running nginx, it works for my 50+ logfiles.

As per the OP, if you do not have zgrep, you can just run the logfiles through gzip first...

OP noted in a different message that this worked for him. This is also taken from msp9011 solution, so giving credit there.

```
cat access.log | awk '{a[$1]++} END {for(i in a) print a[i],i}' |sort -nr
```

OP would like the solution to print lines with greater than 100 requests. It can be done in one awk statement, I think, but I will do it the brute force way:

```
  cat access.log | awk '{a[$1]++} END {for(i in a) print a[i],i}' |awk '$1>100' | sort -nr
```

Comment: You beat me to the `awk` answer by about 45 seconds. The second answer here will not work if IPv6 addresses are in the log.

Comment: I can't use zgrep and grep without cat. My rights is in edit

Comment: Ohhh, good one. I always forget IPv6. I wish it was [simpler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497/regular-expression-that-matches-valid-ipv6-addresses)

Comment: @number9 I want to exclude ip's where less than 100 requests. I tried a couple variants but it doesn't work, can you help pls?

Comment: I updated my solution

Comment: @number9 Thank you, it worked